# post.from.id doesn't work in Custom Audiences in Facebook (Graph API v2.0)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph

After I save `from.id` field of a post or a comment or a like,
for example `10152377240579757`,
and then try to import it in Custom Audiences,
it doesn't accept any of the IDs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Such behavior is by design and not a bug.

FB Support commented on it:

> This is by design. In v2.0 app scoped ID's are now the primary ID that will be exposed by the graph API and those ID's are not intended to be used outside of the context of the individual application.

See the bug report link for details:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/267871043384634/